# Does a Warforged take half damage to all attacks?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, warforged

Does a Warforged take half damage to all attacks?

I got hit with a fireball today in my campaign and took all the damage, but I'm not sure if I was supposed to take half damage or not.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. What makes you think warforged should take half damage or not?

Comment: Note that a fireball is not classified as an attack in D&D 3.5, so you may not be asking quite the right question.

Comment: @MarkWells That depends on the context. Some contexts use “attack” to refer only to things that use an attack roll, while others use “attack” to mean any offensive action. It’s honestly a mess.

Answer (score 8):

Warforged take half “damage” from Conjuration (healing) effects, that is, they are healed for half as much damage as a regular living creature would be. No other effects are halved for them. You might be thinking of the way [fire and electricity damage against objects is halved (and cold damage is quartered)](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/exploration.htm#energyAttacks), but [objects are explicitly defined as inanimate objects with no ability scores](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#nonabilities). Creatures, even constructs, are not objects, and that rule does not apply to them. Extra doubly so with *living* constructs like warforged.

Answer (score 1):

Each entry for warforged found in *Eberron Campaign Setting*, *Monster Manual III*, and *Races of Eberron* mention nothing explicitly about the halving of damage of any kind. The rules elements that have outside definitions (such as the construct type) likewise mention nothing about damage differences (except that normally, constructs are immune to nonlethal damage and a bevy of other things; warforged are special and take nonlethal damage as normal for living creatures).

If you had improved evasion, you'd take half damage from a *fireball* or any similar effect on a failed save, and that's pretty much the only instance of damage halving that a PC warforged could reasonably have (in core, anyway).